# React Native - Cached images disapeared on iOS devices after several days

Tags: ios, image, react-native, caching

I have an advanced issue, I can't find where to look for a solution or fix... Let me explain :

I'm using "react-native-expo-image-cache" library on my app, here is my use case : when the users log in, I need to download several images (between 200 and 3000 depending on their account), and I need to cache those images in order to retrieve them when the user is offline.

At first sight, the app seems to work well, but I'm facing a problem : Some users report that on iOS devices after some day (I don't know exactly how many days, but on my tablet it was around 10 days) the images disappeared, therefore my app is unusable offline anymore (even online, the images won't load anymore...).

I'm not 100% sure the issue is due to this library, but I'm guessing it's a cache issue, even thought I can't find the reason.

It's working well on android, can any of you help me ? Maybe it's iOS cache management taking advantage over my app cache, but on my tablet (where I managed to reproduce the bug, I didn't touch the tablet during the 10 days). Maybe there is an expiration date for the cache ?

Any help is appreciated, it's been several weeks I'm stuck with this ! Thank you ! :)

Comment: image cache libraries on iOS normally have expiry time, i.e after "x" time, images will be booted from cache and will be downloaded again from server. Time would be calculated from last accessed/loaded. There must be setting/configuration to change that time limit

Comment: regardless of expiry, once removed from cache, library should download images again from server.